# Solving system of equations so that it has no solution

Tags: matrix-equations

Find the **value of parameter** $a$, so that the system has no solution.

\begin{bmatrix}
a & 3 & 2 &   & 5 \\
1 & 7 & 3 & = & 13 \\
3 & 1 & a &   & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}

How to do that? I know I am supposed to get 0 0 0 = non-zero value, but how to actually get to the solution? The answer is 13/7.

Comment: Apply Gauss-Elimination and determine for which $a$ we get a row with $3$ zeros on the left.

Comment: Another possibility is to determine for which $a$ the determinant is $0$. But dom't forget to verify for which $a$ there is actually no solution.

Comment: Would you be so kind and actually show me the Gauss-Elimination in this example?

Comment: First of all, swap the first and second column to have no $a's$ in the first column.

Comment: Can I just swap columns?

Comment: Yes, you may swap columns. For there to be a solution, $[5,13,3]^T$ must lie in the column space of the coefficient matrix, for which the order of columns is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from equation (2) we get
$$x_1=13-7x_2-3x_3$$
plugging this in the first and third equation
and we have
$$x_2(3-7a)+x_3(2-3a)=5-13a$$
$$-20x_2+x_3(a-9)=-36$$
from our last equation
$$x_2=\frac{9}{5}+\left(\frac{a-9}{20}\right)x_3$$
and now we can eliminate $$x_2$$
$$x_3((a+1)(7a-13)=8(1+a)$$
can you finish?
if $$7a-13=0$$ so $$a=\frac{13}{7}$$ 
 and we get no solutions.

Comment: Would you be also willing to verify if the answer 13/7 is incorrect? Thank you.

Comment: my Maple says $$\frac{13}{7}$$ is correct

Comment: Then you got something wrong, right?

Comment: yes i have it corrected in my post, sorry for my mistake!

Comment: why have you chosen the second equation as your starting point?